# How to make Spring Boot Test under JUnit 5 resolve indented/hierarchical properties externalized on a YAML file

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

**How to make `Spring Boot Test` under `JUnit 5` resolve indented/hierarchical properties externalized on a YAML file?**

I would like to write tests to validate some logic that depends on [Environment.getProperty(String key)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-):

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class PropertiesReolution_SO_IT {

    @Nested
    @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.yml")
    public class ViaYamlFile {

        @Autowired
        private Environment env;

        @Test
        void testGetDottedHierarchicalProperty() throws Exception {
            final String key = "dotted.hierarchical.property";
            assertNotNull(this.env.getProperty(key));
            assertEquals("application-test.yml", this.env.getProperty(key));
        }
    }

}
```

The `dotted.hierarchical.property` property is defined on the `application-test.yml` YAML file like this:

```yaml
dotted:
  hierarchical:
    property: application-test.yml
```

The test case fails with the property evaluating to `null`. I am locked to spring-boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, so I am using [org.springframework.test:spring-test-junit5](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5). I created a [Gist with the full example](https://gist.github.com/theoamonteiro/2be5fac51afb40488d965e4ac07b6067#file-propertiesreolutionit-java).